# Using a service to getAll IUser

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

In orchard 1.6 I want to get all the records in the 
Orchard_Users_UserPartRecord table

I can get a user by saying:

```
var user = _membershipService.GetUser(username);
```

or

```
 IUser userInfo = _authenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser();
```

is there not a query or service of some sort that allows me to getAllUsers?...im sure there is but I cant see it so iv tried to add my own...

In Orchard.Users module in the membershipService.cs iv added:

```
public IEnumerable<IUser> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query<UserPart, UserPartRecord>().List();
    }
```

tehn in the IUserService iv added:

```
IEnumerable<IUser> AllUsers();
```

and in the userService iv added:

```
 public IEnumerable<IUser> AllUsers()
    {
        IEnumerable<IUser> users = _membershipService.//but it doesnt allow me to select GetAllUsers, but it does allow me to seleect
            //getUser, iv used the same code only changed the query why isnt it showing?
        if (users == null)
            return null;

        return users;
    }
```

then where I needed to get all users I can say:

```
IEnumerable<IUser> allUsers = _userService.AllUsers();
```

I think there is a service that already does this I just dont see it. ANy ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`GetAllUsers()` is not available on `_membershipService`, because `_membershipService` is of the interface type `IMembershipService`, and not of the `MembershipService` class, where you added the `GetAllUsers()` method. To make this available, also add the method declaration for `GetAllUsers()` to the `IMembershipService` interface.

As for whether a service already exists for doing this, it doesn't seem that way.  You can see that Orchard itself uses the same technique as you described above to obtain a list of users, such as in the `AdminController` that comes with the `Orchard.Users` module:

```
var users = Services.ContentManager
    .Query<UserPart, UserPartRecord>();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, Yeah there is no IMembershipService class, but surely i shouldnt have to create one as these modules should be correct?..So in the same folder there is a userService and an IUserService i figured there is a reason there is no IMembershipService?

Comment: `IMembershipService` is an interface in `Orchard.Security` (part of `Orchard.Framework`).  `MembershipService` in `Orchard.Users` is a class that implements that interface.

`IMembershipService` is supposed to be a framework interface, i.e., something that is expected to be implemented by some module.  If you wanted to, you could provide an alternate implementation based on something other than `UserPart` (such as LDAP or Active Directory).

Comment: When the authors of Orchard designed the `IMembershipService` interface, they didn't feel the need to provide a way to query for all users.  Maybe it doesn't make sense for some membership providers, or maybe it's something that just didn't occur to them.  You might want to try asking someone on the team.